# semantic ui wont switch to mobile view

Tags: mobile, semantic-ui

My webpage looks fine in my browser with semantic-ui. If the browser window is scaled down, semantic-ui behaves correctly.

When the same page is viewed on a mobile device, the page appears like in a browser but very small and no mobile-view is displayed (even when i play with the mobile browser settings).

[image: website code]

How can the mobile-view be triggered correctly?

Comment: Hi, did you solve this? im having the exactly same problem

Answer (score 5):

To solve this, just put the viewport-tag in your `<head>`

something like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

Please create the head definitions outside of any template.